# Groups and graphs

Tags: gr.group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups

Let $A=(V, E)$ be a finite simple (no loops or multiple edges)  graph. Let $G(A)$ be the following nilpotent group of class 2 and exponent $p$ (an odd prime). $G(A)$ as a set is $span(V)+span(E)$ where $span(X)$ is the elementary abelian group of exponent $p$ generated by the set $X$, and the commutator bracket is given by 1) the subgroup $span(E)$ is the center, 2) if $a,b\in V$ then $[a,b]=e\in E$ if  $e$ is the edge connecting $a, b$ in $A$ or $=1$ if there is no edge $(a,b)$ or $(b,a)$. It is clear that every automorphism of the graph $A$ induces an automorphism of the group $G(A)$.

*Question 1*: Can $Aut(G(A))$ be much bigger than $Aut(A)$?

**Update** Derek Holt in his comments below showed that $Aut(G(A))$ always contains an elementary abelian normal subgroup of order $p^{|V||E|}$. Here is a more concrete question.

*Question 2*. Is it true that $Aut(G(A))$ comtains an involution iff $Aut(A)$ contains an involution?

This is related to [Automorphism groups of odd order](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351715/automorphism-groups-of-odd-order).

The positive answer to the next question would imply the positive answer to Question 2.

*Question 3.* Let $Q$ be the subgoup of $Aut (G(A))$ consisting of all automorphisms induced by the automorphisms of $A$. Is it true that $Aut(G(A))$ is equal to a semidirect product of $P$ and $Q$?

Comment: Depends on the word *much*. When the graph is the discrete with $n$ vertices, the numbers are easily computed and the size of $\textit{Aut}(G(A))$ (namely $[n]_p!(p-1)^np^{C(n,2)}$) is larger than the size of $\textit{Aut}(A)$ (which is only $n!$). If you demand nilpotence class exactly two, do the same construction but add one edge. The numbers should be about the same.

Comment: ${\rm Aut}(G(A)$ has a normal elementary abelian $p$-subgroup $P$, say, of order $p^{|V||E|}$ consisting of those automorphisms that induce the identity on $G(A)/G(A)'$, which does not occur as a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(A)$. It would make more sense to compare ${\rm Aut}(A)$ with ${\rm Aut}(G(A)/P$. But the latter is still much bigger in general, because it is a subgroup of ${\rm GL}(|V|,p)$ rather than of ${\rm Sym}(|V|)$. If the graph is empty or complete then we get the whole of ${\rm GL}(|V|,p)$.

Comment: @Keith: I was thinking of generic graphs, highly connected but not full.

Comment: @Derek: Is it true that the number of elements in $P$ is   that large?  Take the graph with two verticed and one edge (the Heisenberg group of order $p^3$).

Comment: Would benefit of being tagged in addition graph-theory and finite-groups, maybe also p-groups, and of having a more specific title.

Comment: For any $a \in V$ and any $e \in E$, map $a \to ae$ and $a' \to a'$ for all $a'\in V \setminus \{a\}$. That gives a generating set for $P$ os size $|V|E|$. So this subgroup has order $p^2$ for the Heisenberg group.

Comment: I believe a random graph has trivial automorphism group with high probability.

Comment: @Derek:The infinite random graph is highly symmetric. Thank you for the explanation about $P$.

Comment: Certainly Derek means a finite set of cardinal $n$ with a random graph structure, say we link a pair with fixed probability $0<t<1$. Then (I expect that) the probability $u_n(t)$ that the resulting graph has trivial automorphism group tends to $1$ when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Yes, I meant what YCor said - I was talking about a random finite graph on a large number of vertices. Incidentally, ${\rm Aut}(G(A))/P$ always has a central subgroup of order $p-1$ acting as scalar elements of ${\rm GL}(|V|,p)$. I would guess that, when $A$ is a random graph on a large number of vertices, then that with high probability that is the whole of ${\rm Aut}(G(A))$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I added the second question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's time to write an answer.

Let $G = G(A)$, so $|G| = p^{|V|+|E|}$ with $|G'| = p^{|E|}$ and $G'$ and $G/G'$ are both elementary abelian ($p$-groups with that property are called *special* $p$-groups, and it is conjectured that almost all finite groups of order up to some bound are special $2$-groups, but that's not relevant to this question.) Note also that by definition $G$ has exponent $p$ and $p$ is odd.

Let $A_G := {\rm Aut}(G)$. As I mentioned in a comment, $A_G$ has a normal elementary abelian subgroup of order $p^{|V|+|E|}$, consisting of those automorphisms that induce the identity on $G/G'$, and hence also on $G'$.

I also mentioned that $A_G$ has another subgroup $Q$, which is cyclic of order $q-1$, and consists of automophisms that induce a scalar linear map on $G/G'$. To define $Q$ precisely, choose any transversal $T$ of $G'$ in $G$. Then a generator of $Q$ maps every element $g \in T$ to $g^{\lambda}$, where $\lambda$  generates the multiplicative group of integers mod $p$, and it maps $g \to g^{\lambda^2}$ for all $g \in G'$. Note that there are $p^{|V| + |E|}$ choices for $T$, and different choices give you conjugates of $Q$ under elements of $P$. Also $QP/P \unlhd A_G/P$. The fact that this really does define an automorphism follows from the fact that it preserves all of the relations in a presentation defining $G$.

So in particular, since $p$ is odd, $A_G$ always has even order, so the answers to Questions 2 and 3 are both no.

You could still ask whether $A_G$ is the semidirect product of $QP$ and the automorphisms of $A_G$ induced from ${\rm Aut}(A)$. The answer to this is again no in general, and it's easy to find small examples in which $A_G$ is bigger, but it is possible that in some sense generically true for random graphs.

This is a difficult topic to investigate computationally, because $A_G$ gets very hard to calculate once $|V|$ is bigger than about 6, and I expect you would need to consider much larger examples in order to get any feel for the generic situation.

But I did do the calculation (in Magma) with a graph with 6 vertices and 6 edges that has trivial automorphism group. The order of $A_G$ turned out to be $2^6 \times 3^{43}$, whereas $PQ| = 2 \times 3^{36}$.

Comment: @DerekbHolt: Thank you!